# Output a number up to N decimal places withoud rounding

Tags: python-3.x, floating-point

If i have the number 1.2348 and I used the round function to round it to 3 decimal places, I would get 1.235 but I want to get 1.234. If i did:

```
num=1.2348
print(str(num)[:5])
```

I would get a string and if I tried to convert that string to an int back again(because I need it to be an int) it raises a ValueError.

Comment: What do you need to be an int?  Hopefully it isn't 1.234, because that will never be an int.

Comment: I meant float, your answer worked,thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do what you want:

```
>>> int(num*1000)/1000.0
1.234
```

Unless you encounter a round-off error.